# Divide column output

Tags: sql-server-2008

I might be asking this question completely incorrect, but here we.
I am creating a stored procedure to insert whether the output of a column is one of 3 values, then it is true for each facility.

The column name is container, the 3 values are cans, bottles, kegs or False.

```
SELECT --DISTINCT
        ShiptoID = ID,  
        dba_Name = LEFT(MAX(Dba_Name), 35),
        LicName = LEFT(MAX(LicName), 35),
        Addr1 = MAX(Addr1),
        City = MAX(City),
        State = MAX(State),
        Zipcode = MAX(Zipcode),
        AreaCode = MAX(AreaCode),
                container....CASE 
            WHEN pl.container = Cans THEN 'TRUE'
            WHEN pl.Container = Bottles THEN 'TRUE'
            WHEN pl.container = Kegs THEN 'TRUE'
        ELSE  'FALSE'
        END,
                Lastupdate
```

I have tried it in the SELECT and WHERE clauses and haven't been able to get the syntax correct.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You need single quotes around Cans, Bottles and Kegs.  Ex 'Cans' 'Bottles' 'Kegs'

Answer (score 0):

`               Cans = pl.Container,
        Bottles = pl.Container,
        Kegs = pl.Container,
        LastUpdate = GETDATE () --@Today

```
FROM dbo.vw_RtlSalesNew rs with (nolock) 
INNER JOIN MM_Data.dbo.vw_VBS_Prodlist_UXT pl with (nolock) 
    ON pl.ProdUID = rs.ProdUID
WHERE rs.InvoiceDate >= '2015-12-01' --BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    AND ro.CoTCode NOT IN(*..)  
    AND (SELECT *
        CASE 
        WHEN pl.container = 'Cans' THEN 'Cans'
        WHEN pl.Container = 'Bottles' THEN 'Bottles'
        WHEN pl.container = 'Kegs' THEN 'Kegs'
    ELSE  'FALSE'
    END )`
```

How about this: